# Rename a file based on the owner - linux/Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have several files in a folder that all follow a naming convention of:

```
 rs1.txt  
 rs2.txt
 rs3.txt
```

Some of these files were produced by myself, and some were produced by my colleague.
I was hoping to change the file name based on who owns the file. So if we have

```
 rs1.txt  ME 
 rs2.txt  ME
 rs3.txt  HIM
```

My files would change to:

```
 srs1.txt  ME 
 srs2.txt  ME
 rs3.txt  HIM
```

Is there any conceivable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -user ME -exec mv {} s{} \;
```

This looks for files owned by `ME` and runs an `mv` command on each one.  This time, you do not want the `+` option at the end (which is often preferred).  You can add constraints to the list of files as you like: `-name rs*.txt`, for example.

Comment: Why don't I want the + option? Could you explain?

Comment: You couldn't call mv{} s{} directly, because of trailing path. You'll get something like: mv ./test.txt s./test.txt. That isn't correct. You should use printf and then call mv.

Comment: @OlegSKleshchook Could you show me what you mean? find . -user ME -printf -exec mv {} s{} \;  ??

Comment: @User101 find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -user $USER -printf "%f\n" | xargs -I {}  mv {} s{}

Comment: @OlegSKleshchook find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -user Stephanie -printf "%f\n" -name rs*.vcf | xargs -l {} mv {} s{}
xargs: {}: No such file or directory

Comment: @User101 Are there actually any files in current dir, which are owned by Stephanie?

Comment: @User101 Oops. My bad. Looks it must be -maxdepth 1

Comment: The `+` is useful when you want to provide a list of file names to a single invocation of the command.  Here, though, you want to execute each `mv` with just two arguments (old name and new name), so you need to execute `mv` once for each file that's found.  Or you use a more complex `rename` command, such as a Perl-based one that can do a regex mapping, so `-exec rename 's/^/s/' {} +` is now appropriate.  (Beware: there are several sub-species of command called `rename`, and they're mostly feeble by comparison with the Perl-based one.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. this renames all files in the current directory with user 'ME', prepending 's' to the name.

```
for f in *
do
    owner=$(ls -l | awk '{print $3}')
    if [ $owner = ME ];then
       mv $f s$f
    fi
done
```

Comment: ~~If I try this:~~ for f in *; do owner=$(ls -l |awk 'print $3}'); if [$owner -eq Stephanie ]; then mv $f s$f; fi; done                      
~~I get this response over and over:~~                                   awk: print $3}
awk: ^ syntax error
bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
awk: print $3}
awk: ^ syntax error
bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
awk: print $3} ~~Am I missing something?~~

Comment: sorry about that. I've updated the answer. Changed -eq to =. But the find solution is better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I just like to try all the answers I get. I find it helps me get to know some of the commands better. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
USER="ME"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -user $USER -printf "%f\n" | xargs -I {}  mv {} s{}
```

Answer (score 0):

ls -l |fgrep ME|awk '{print "mv " $NF " " $NF.1}'

Answer (score 0):

1337 }{4xx0|22 |>0 !7 1!|<3 7}{!5:

```
for i in `echo $(ls -n | grep \
  \`getent passwd |grep $USER| cut -d: -f3\` | 
  awk '{print $NF}')`; do 
      if [[ -f $i ]]; then echo mv \"$i\" \"s${i}\"; 
 fi ;done | sh
```